# MySQL rowrank based on ORDER BY on 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The database has the table `persons`:

```
id          int
points      int
voted_on    int 
other columns
```

I want to know which row rank the row with `id` x has, rows with same points has same row rank. This query works great and fast: (but tell me if you know even better one:)

```
select count(*)
from persons p cross join
     (select points from persons p where p.id = x) const
where p.points > const.points;
```

But now I would like to upgrade the query that people with less voted_on, but same amount of points, have a better row rank than people with more voted_on. However, people with same amount of points and voted_on should have the same row rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a more complex `where` clause:

```
select count(*)
from persons p cross join
     (select points, voted_on from persons p where p.id = x) const
where (p.points > const.points) or
      (p.points = const.points and p.voted_on >= const.voted_on)
```

I'm not sure if "better" means a lower rank or a higher rank.  This gives people a higher rank if `voted_on` is bigger.  For a lower rank, change the `>=` to `<=`.

EDIT:

I believe this works for the "lowest" row rank (as per your comment):

```
select count(*) + 1
from persons p cross join
     (select points, voted_on from persons p where p.id = x) const
where (p.points > const.points) or
      (p.points = const.points and p.voted_on > const.voted_on)
```

This will start the ranking at "1" rather than at "0".

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, but I would prefer to give them all the highest row rank, the above query gives all 3 the lowest. If there are 6 people in the database, and people 2 till 4 has the same amount of points and voted_on, how give them all the rowrank of 2 (instead of 4). Thanks again and sorry, should have said this before. And would your query fancy an index on (id, voted_on)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, works as a charm, last question: would i need an extra index to speed it up? Got only (id, points) at the moment.

Comment: @KevinVermaat . . . An index on `points, voted_on` would probably help, as would an index on `id` (for the subquery).  If you need the values for more than one "x", then ask another question.  That problem might have a very different solution.

Comment: the indexes you suggested, those are normal indexes or you mean (p.id, points) and (p.id, p.voted_on)?

Comment: And what is the secret behind this query? It is so fast, I do not understand, (got non-composite indexes at the moment).

Comment: @KevinVermaat . . . The indexes make the inequality count much, much faster.  It is a partial index scan for each row rather than a full table scan for each row.

Comment: Gordon linoff thanks again, could you take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026889/sql-select-query-order-by-on-2-columns-and-where-clause-big-table, I think you are the right person to ask. Not getting many answers :/